# Convert Matlab output into ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, matlab

I'm doing sampling from log-normal distribution in Java using Matlab code (with javabuilder java).

Here is the code :

```
import demo2.*;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ht {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Object[] x = null; //?? What does Object[] mean?//
ArrayList th = new ArrayList();
demo y = null;

try {
    y = new demo();    //the class created by Matlab builder ja//
    x=y.lognorma(1, 10); //function to sample the distribution//


} catch (MWException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

What does Object[] mean in this context and how to change Object[] x into normal ArrayList in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of "catch" block add

```
th = new ArrayList(x);
```

or

```
List<Object> res = Arrays.asList(x);
```